# Use F value as dict key for ordering django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, key

I am developing a Django website and I have the following models (simplified):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    opinions = JSONField(default=default_opinions)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='0')
```

with the opinions field being the opinion that a specific user has of the different authors:
Exemple:

```
{
   Shakespeare: 0.5,
   Voltaire: 0.6
}
```

Then I have a listView BookListView, in which I want to query the Book database, and order them by the opinion the currently logged in user has of their author.
In the previous example it would be all the Voltaire's books first, then the Shakespeare's ones.

So I came up with this in my listView:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user_opinions = self.request.user.profile.opinions
    queryset = Book.objects.order_by(user_opinions[F("author__name")])
    return queryset
```

The problem is the F value is computed after the get_queryset(), so I get a F("author__name") key does not exist error.

I thought about iterating through the dict keys and values but I don't see how that could work since opinions are floats (and thus can take any values).

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Is this a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a float can take any value?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm: I think he wants to obtain the value in the dictionary with the corresponding key.

Comment: In a relational database however, this is often modeled through the junction table between two models.

Comment: So he was considering using the non-unique floats as keys?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm What I meant is if the value space was non infinite (like integers between 1 and 10) I could have iterated through the dict and order my query elements by checking the values (all the element with a score of 10, then score of 9 etc ...).

Willem I'm using an SQLite database for development

Answer (score 0):

F expressions doesn't support JSON field lookup,that's why you are getting error key does not exist, because it is trying to find field named with that and running join on that field,
Can you elaborate more, on what key and value pair are there in json Field

Comment: It's almost exactly as I said. I cannot give the exact content of the database (for privacy reasons) but the keys are strings and the values are tuples of integers.

I said floats for values to simplify the problem description.